# Parse results from JSON to a list dynamically

Tags: json, swift, google-maps

I do a JSON Request and get some information.

```
func parseJSON(poiData: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(POIData.self, from: poiData)

        POIManager.POIname_One = decodedData.results[0].name
        POIManager.POIplaceid_One = decodedData.results[4].place_id
        POIManager.POIvicinity_One = decodedData.results[4].vicinity
        POIManager.POIlong_One = decodedData.results[0].geometry.location.lat
        POIManager.POIlat_One = decodedData.results[0].geometry.location.lng

        POIManager.POIname_Two = decodedData.results[1].name
        POIManager.POIplaceid_Two = decodedData.results[1].place_id
        POIManager.POIvicinity_Two = decodedData.results[1].vicinity
        POIManager.POIlong_Two = decodedData.results[1].geometry.location.lat
        POIManager.POIlat_Two = decodedData.results[1].geometry.location.lng
        
        POIManager.POIname_Three = decodedData.results[2].name
        POIManager.POIplaceid_Three = decodedData.results[2].place_id
        POIManager.POIvicinity_Three = decodedData.results[2].vicinity
        POIManager.POIlong_Three = decodedData.results[2].geometry.location.lat
        POIManager.POIlat_Three = decodedData.results[2].geometry.location.lng

        
    } catch {
        print(error)
    } 
}
```

In a different Swift file it put the results from the request in a list like this:

```
@IBAction func kategorieEins(_ sender: UIButton) {
       
        //Eigene Standort soll hier gezeigt werden/aktualisierter Standort
        locationManager.delegate=self

        let marker1 = GMSMarker()
        marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: POIManager.POIlong_One, longitude: POIManager.POIlat_One)
        marker1.title = POIManager.POIname_One
        marker1.snippet = "Marker1_0"
        marker1.map = mapView
        
        let marker2 = GMSMarker()
        marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: POIManager.POIlong_Two, longitude: POIManager.POIlat_Two)
        marker2.title = POIManager.POIname_Two
        marker2.snippet = "Marker2_0"
        marker2.map = mapView
        
        let marker3 = GMSMarker()
        marker3.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: POIManager.POIlong_Three, longitude: POIManager.POIlat_Three)
        marker3.title = POIManager.POIname_Three
        marker3.snippet = "Marker3_0"
        marker3.map = mapView
   
    }
```

As you can see this whole thing is not dynamic it is static. I write down how many markers i want to have created.
Is there a way to do this automatically? Especially when I dont know how much information there is in the json file and how many markers should be created.

Comment: May I suggest you learn about collection types and how to iterate them, https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html. You iterate over decodedData.results and create a new POIManager (or whatever the name of the type is) for each iteration and add it to an array. Then you iterate over this array and create GMSMarker objects for each element in the array

Comment: Thank you for the link. I really tried to understand but cant do it by my own. Any more links or articles which I can read? I tried somethings like this: for results in decodedData {
            print(results)
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now.
I tried:

```
    decodedData.results.forEach {
        print($0.name)
        print($0.place_id)
    }
```